# PHPUnit. Error: No code coverage driver is available. (having xdebug installed)

Tags: php, phpunit, wamp

There is an answer for similar question [Laravel 5: PHPUnit and no code coverage driver available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811503/laravel-5-phpunit-and-no-code-coverage-driver-available) that works, but i have xdebug installed.

(if this matter I'm using: windows7, netbeans8.1, php7, wamp3)

Displaying code coverage in Netbeans result in:

> Error: No code coverage driver is available

,
and the output is below:

> "C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnitSymfony2.8\bin\phpunit.bat" "--colors"
>   "--log-junit" "C:\Users\chiny\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml"
>   "--coverage-clover"
>   "C:\Users\chiny\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-coverage.xml"
>   "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--"
>   "--run=C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnitSymfony2.8\src\TreningBundle\Tests\Controller\RabarbarControllerTest.php"
>   PHPUnit 5.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Error:         No code coverage driver is available
>
> .II                                                                3 /
>   3 (100%)
>
> Time: 1.13 seconds, Memory: 4.00MB
>
> OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests! Tests: 3, Assertions: 1,
>   Incomplete: 2. Done.](url)

xdebug conf (C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.1/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0rc3-7.0-vc14.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

loaded extensions
[image: wamp. loaded extension]

(I have netbeans and project directory in same Windows partition)

Comment: What is `php.exe -v` telling you? Is xdebug enabled?

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>php.exe -v
PHP 7.0.1 (cli) (built: Dec 16 2015 13:36:30) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Comment: xdebug as shown in last printscreen in main post is on the list

Comment: xdebug is not enabled in CLI. Enable it and it should work.

Comment: thanks, I will google that. I though that if extension is on that list i put meaning it's enable.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are 2 `php.ini` files in most Apache/PHP installations and definitely in WAMPServer

To amend the correct `php.ini` used by PHP in Apache use the menus

```
wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

But for the `php.ini` file used by the PHP CLI you have to manually edit

```
\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini
```

the result of a `php -v` should look like this if XDEBUG is configured in the CLI

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.6 (cli) (built: Apr 27 2016 14:00:40) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

**NOTE**

The current WAMPServer 3 is `3.0.4`
ADDON upgrades can be found on SourceForge

The latest ADDON PHP Version is PHP7.0.6 also available on SourceForge

See [The WampServer Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) to keep up to date with the latest releases of PHP / MYSQL / Apache ADDONS for WAMPServer 3

Also :

You may find that you have to [tweek the XDEBUG config parameters](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) in the `php.ini` to suit your specific needs

Comment: that's right. the result of a `php -v` now showing xdebug

Comment: After editing php.ini in php directory there is no more `Error: No code coverage driver is available` instead i have new `Error:No whitelist configured, no code coverage will be generated` but that's a progress, i think, and a issue for new google search and another topic. Thanks for all tips!

Comment: Take a look at the XDEBUG documentation, specifically `xdebug.coverage_enable`

Answer (score 13):

I've faced this problem with a new installation of PHP 7.1 and this is what I've done to make it work

`$ brew install php71-xdebug`

`$ php -i | grep xdebug` // to check if xdebug was installed

`$ phpunit`

After that it worked. Additionally this is how my phpunit.xml looks like I've needed to whitelist whole structure because it's shared component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Tests">
            <directory suffix=".php">./Tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./build/logs/clover.xml"/>
    </logging>
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

This solution will work on MacOS only, if you want to make it work on Linux then you need to use applicable package manager like apt-get etc.

Comment: yep, on linux you need to use other package manager like apt-get on debian systems

Comment: If Fedora GNU/Linux you can use `sudo dnf install php-xdebug` it will install the package for which ever version of php you have.

Answer (score 11):

With the same problem on Debian:

> Error: No code coverage driver is available

I fixed it with installing php-xdebug: `sudo apt install php-xdebug`

Comment: In my case it was installed but disabled by the author of the Docker image during the build. I needed `phpenmod xdebug`

Answer (score 4):

`xdebug.mode=coverage` has to be set in `php.ini`.